# Label only 10 N in D3 graph nodes

Tags: d3.js, label

I have a force-directed graph in D3.js similar to this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

With the data source for nodes having an additional key:value called connect. I only want to display node labels that have the top 10 count by the connect value. How should I go about it?

Thank you!

The associated sample data source this as below.

```
{
"nodes": [
  {"name": "Myriel", "company": 1, "connect":10},
  {"name": "Napoleon", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mlle.Baptistine", "company": 1, "connect":3},
  {"name": "Mme.Magloire", "company": 1, "connect":3},
  {"name": "CountessdeLo", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Geborand", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Champtercier", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Cravatte", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Count", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "OldMan", "company": 1, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Labarre", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Valjean", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Marguerite", "company": 3, "connect":3},
  {"name": "Mme.deR", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Isabeau", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Gervais", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Tholomyes", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Listolier", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Fameuil", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Blacheville", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Favourite", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Dahlia", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Zephine", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Fantine", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mme.Thenardier", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Thenardier", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Cosette", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Javert", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Fauchelevent", "company": 0, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Bamatabois", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Perpetue", "company": 3, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Simplice", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Scaufflaire", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Woman1", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Judge", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Champmathieu", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Brevet", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Chenildieu", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Cochepaille", "company": 2, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Pontmercy", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Boulatruelle", "company": 6, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Eponine", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Anzelma", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Woman2", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "MotherInnocent", "company": 0, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Gribier", "company": 0, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Jondrette", "company": 7, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mme.Burgon", "company": 7, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Gavroche", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Gillenormand", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Magnon", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "company": 5, "connect":5},
  {"name": "Mme.Pontmercy", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mlle.Vaubois", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Lt.Gillenormand", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Marius", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "BaronessT", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mabeuf", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Enjolras", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Combeferre", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Prouvaire", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Feuilly", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Courfeyrac", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Bahorel", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Bossuet", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Joly", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Grantaire", "company": 8, "connect":1},
  {"name": "MotherPlutarch", "company": 9, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Gueulemer", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Babet", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Claquesous", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Montparnasse", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Toussaint", "company": 5, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Child1", "company": 10, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Child2", "company": 10, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Brujon", "company": 4, "connect":1},
  {"name": "Mme.Hucheloup", "company": 8, "connect":1}
],
"links": [
  {"source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1},
  {"source": 2, "target": 0, "value": 8},
  {"source": 3, "target": 0, "value": 10},
  {"source": 3, "target": 2, "value": 6},
  {"source": 4, "target": 0, "value": 1},
  {"source": 5, "target": 0, "value": 1},
  {"source": 6, "target": 0, "value": 1},
  {"source": 7, "target": 0, "value": 1},
  {"source": 8, "target": 0, "value": 2},
  {"source": 9, "target": 0, "value": 1},
  {"source": 11, "target": 10, "value": 1},
  {"source": 11, "target": 3, "value": 3},
  {"source": 11, "target": 2, "value": 3},
  {"source": 11, "target": 0, "value": 5},
  {"source": 12, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 13, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 14, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 15, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 17, "target": 16, "value": 4},
  {"source": 18, "target": 16, "value": 4},
  {"source": 18, "target": 17, "value": 4},
  {"source": 19, "target": 16, "value": 4},
  {"source": 19, "target": 17, "value": 4},
  {"source": 19, "target": 18, "value": 4},
  {"source": 20, "target": 16, "value": 3},
  {"source": 20, "target": 17, "value": 3},
  {"source": 20, "target": 18, "value": 3},
  {"source": 20, "target": 19, "value": 4},
  {"source": 21, "target": 16, "value": 3},
  {"source": 21, "target": 17, "value": 3},
  {"source": 21, "target": 18, "value": 3},
  {"source": 21, "target": 19, "value": 3},
  {"source": 21, "target": 20, "value": 5},
  {"source": 22, "target": 16, "value": 3},
  {"source": 22, "target": 17, "value": 3},
  {"source": 22, "target": 18, "value": 3},
  {"source": 22, "target": 19, "value": 3},
  {"source": 22, "target": 20, "value": 4},
  {"source": 22, "target": 21, "value": 4},
  {"source": 23, "target": 16, "value": 3},
  {"source": 23, "target": 17, "value": 3},
  {"source": 23, "target": 18, "value": 3},
  {"source": 23, "target": 19, "value": 3},
  {"source": 23, "target": 20, "value": 4},
  {"source": 23, "target": 21, "value": 4},
  {"source": 23, "target": 22, "value": 4},
  {"source": 23, "target": 12, "value": 2},
  {"source": 23, "target": 11, "value": 9},
  {"source": 24, "target": 23, "value": 2},
  {"source": 24, "target": 11, "value": 7},
  {"source": 25, "target": 24, "value": 13},
  {"source": 25, "target": 23, "value": 1},
  {"source": 25, "target": 11, "value": 12},
  {"source": 26, "target": 24, "value": 4},
  {"source": 26, "target": 11, "value": 31},
  {"source": 26, "target": 16, "value": 1},
  {"source": 26, "target": 25, "value": 1},
  {"source": 27, "target": 11, "value": 17},
  {"source": 27, "target": 23, "value": 5},
  {"source": 27, "target": 25, "value": 5},
  {"source": 27, "target": 24, "value": 1},
  {"source": 27, "target": 26, "value": 1},
  {"source": 28, "target": 11, "value": 8},
  {"source": 28, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 29, "target": 23, "value": 1},
  {"source": 29, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 29, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 30, "target": 23, "value": 1},
  {"source": 31, "target": 30, "value": 2},
  {"source": 31, "target": 11, "value": 3},
  {"source": 31, "target": 23, "value": 2},
  {"source": 31, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 32, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 33, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 33, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 34, "target": 11, "value": 3},
  {"source": 34, "target": 29, "value": 2},
  {"source": 35, "target": 11, "value": 3},
  {"source": 35, "target": 34, "value": 3},
  {"source": 35, "target": 29, "value": 2},
  {"source": 36, "target": 34, "value": 2},
  {"source": 36, "target": 35, "value": 2},
  {"source": 36, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 36, "target": 29, "value": 1},
  {"source": 37, "target": 34, "value": 2},
  {"source": 37, "target": 35, "value": 2},
  {"source": 37, "target": 36, "value": 2},
  {"source": 37, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 37, "target": 29, "value": 1},
  {"source": 38, "target": 34, "value": 2},
  {"source": 38, "target": 35, "value": 2},
  {"source": 38, "target": 36, "value": 2},
  {"source": 38, "target": 37, "value": 2},
  {"source": 38, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 38, "target": 29, "value": 1},
  {"source": 39, "target": 25, "value": 1},
  {"source": 40, "target": 25, "value": 1},
  {"source": 41, "target": 24, "value": 2},
  {"source": 41, "target": 25, "value": 3},
  {"source": 42, "target": 41, "value": 2},
  {"source": 42, "target": 25, "value": 2},
  {"source": 42, "target": 24, "value": 1},
  {"source": 43, "target": 11, "value": 3},
  {"source": 43, "target": 26, "value": 1},
  {"source": 43, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 44, "target": 28, "value": 3},
  {"source": 44, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 45, "target": 28, "value": 2},
  {"source": 47, "target": 46, "value": 1},
  {"source": 48, "target": 47, "value": 2},
  {"source": 48, "target": 25, "value": 1},
  {"source": 48, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 48, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 49, "target": 26, "value": 3},
  {"source": 49, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 50, "target": 49, "value": 1},
  {"source": 50, "target": 24, "value": 1},
  {"source": 51, "target": 49, "value": 9},
  {"source": 51, "target": 26, "value": 2},
  {"source": 51, "target": 11, "value": 2},
  {"source": 52, "target": 51, "value": 1},
  {"source": 52, "target": 39, "value": 1},
  {"source": 53, "target": 51, "value": 1},
  {"source": 54, "target": 51, "value": 2},
  {"source": 54, "target": 49, "value": 1},
  {"source": 54, "target": 26, "value": 1},
  {"source": 55, "target": 51, "value": 6},
  {"source": 55, "target": 49, "value": 12},
  {"source": 55, "target": 39, "value": 1},
  {"source": 55, "target": 54, "value": 1},
  {"source": 55, "target": 26, "value": 21},
  {"source": 55, "target": 11, "value": 19},
  {"source": 55, "target": 16, "value": 1},
  {"source": 55, "target": 25, "value": 2},
  {"source": 55, "target": 41, "value": 5},
  {"source": 55, "target": 48, "value": 4},
  {"source": 56, "target": 49, "value": 1},
  {"source": 56, "target": 55, "value": 1},
  {"source": 57, "target": 55, "value": 1},
  {"source": 57, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 57, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 58, "target": 55, "value": 7},
  {"source": 58, "target": 48, "value": 7},
  {"source": 58, "target": 27, "value": 6},
  {"source": 58, "target": 57, "value": 1},
  {"source": 58, "target": 11, "value": 4},
  {"source": 59, "target": 58, "value": 15},
  {"source": 59, "target": 55, "value": 5},
  {"source": 59, "target": 48, "value": 6},
  {"source": 59, "target": 57, "value": 2},
  {"source": 60, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 60, "target": 58, "value": 4},
  {"source": 60, "target": 59, "value": 2},
  {"source": 61, "target": 48, "value": 2},
  {"source": 61, "target": 58, "value": 6},
  {"source": 61, "target": 60, "value": 2},
  {"source": 61, "target": 59, "value": 5},
  {"source": 61, "target": 57, "value": 1},
  {"source": 61, "target": 55, "value": 1},
  {"source": 62, "target": 55, "value": 9},
  {"source": 62, "target": 58, "value": 17},
  {"source": 62, "target": 59, "value": 13},
  {"source": 62, "target": 48, "value": 7},
  {"source": 62, "target": 57, "value": 2},
  {"source": 62, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 62, "target": 61, "value": 6},
  {"source": 62, "target": 60, "value": 3},
  {"source": 63, "target": 59, "value": 5},
  {"source": 63, "target": 48, "value": 5},
  {"source": 63, "target": 62, "value": 6},
  {"source": 63, "target": 57, "value": 2},
  {"source": 63, "target": 58, "value": 4},
  {"source": 63, "target": 61, "value": 3},
  {"source": 63, "target": 60, "value": 2},
  {"source": 63, "target": 55, "value": 1},
  {"source": 64, "target": 55, "value": 5},
  {"source": 64, "target": 62, "value": 12},
  {"source": 64, "target": 48, "value": 5},
  {"source": 64, "target": 63, "value": 4},
  {"source": 64, "target": 58, "value": 10},
  {"source": 64, "target": 61, "value": 6},
  {"source": 64, "target": 60, "value": 2},
  {"source": 64, "target": 59, "value": 9},
  {"source": 64, "target": 57, "value": 1},
  {"source": 64, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 65, "target": 63, "value": 5},
  {"source": 65, "target": 64, "value": 7},
  {"source": 65, "target": 48, "value": 3},
  {"source": 65, "target": 62, "value": 5},
  {"source": 65, "target": 58, "value": 5},
  {"source": 65, "target": 61, "value": 5},
  {"source": 65, "target": 60, "value": 2},
  {"source": 65, "target": 59, "value": 5},
  {"source": 65, "target": 57, "value": 1},
  {"source": 65, "target": 55, "value": 2},
  {"source": 66, "target": 64, "value": 3},
  {"source": 66, "target": 58, "value": 3},
  {"source": 66, "target": 59, "value": 1},
  {"source": 66, "target": 62, "value": 2},
  {"source": 66, "target": 65, "value": 2},
  {"source": 66, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 66, "target": 63, "value": 1},
  {"source": 66, "target": 61, "value": 1},
  {"source": 66, "target": 60, "value": 1},
  {"source": 67, "target": 57, "value": 3},
  {"source": 68, "target": 25, "value": 5},
  {"source": 68, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 68, "target": 24, "value": 1},
  {"source": 68, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 68, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 68, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 69, "target": 25, "value": 6},
  {"source": 69, "target": 68, "value": 6},
  {"source": 69, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 69, "target": 24, "value": 1},
  {"source": 69, "target": 27, "value": 2},
  {"source": 69, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 69, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 70, "target": 25, "value": 4},
  {"source": 70, "target": 69, "value": 4},
  {"source": 70, "target": 68, "value": 4},
  {"source": 70, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 70, "target": 24, "value": 1},
  {"source": 70, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 70, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 70, "target": 58, "value": 1},
  {"source": 71, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 71, "target": 69, "value": 2},
  {"source": 71, "target": 68, "value": 2},
  {"source": 71, "target": 70, "value": 2},
  {"source": 71, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 71, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 71, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 71, "target": 25, "value": 1},
  {"source": 72, "target": 26, "value": 2},
  {"source": 72, "target": 27, "value": 1},
  {"source": 72, "target": 11, "value": 1},
  {"source": 73, "target": 48, "value": 2},
  {"source": 74, "target": 48, "value": 2},
  {"source": 74, "target": 73, "value": 3},
  {"source": 75, "target": 69, "value": 3},
  {"source": 75, "target": 68, "value": 3},
  {"source": 75, "target": 25, "value": 3},
  {"source": 75, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 75, "target": 41, "value": 1},
  {"source": 75, "target": 70, "value": 1},
  {"source": 75, "target": 71, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 64, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 65, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 66, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 63, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 62, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 48, "value": 1},
  {"source": 76, "target": 58, "value": 1}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of [Mike Bostock's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) which only displays labels of top 10 nodes:

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

var json = {"nodes":[{"name":"Myriel","group":1},{"name":"Napoleon","group":1},{"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},{"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},{"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},{"name":"Geborand","group":1},{"name":"Champtercier","group":1},{"name":"Cravatte","group":1},{"name":"Count","group":1},{"name":"OldMan","group":1},{"name":"Labarre","group":2},{"name":"Valjean","group":2},{"name":"Marguerite","group":3},{"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},{"name":"Isabeau","group":2},{"name":"Gervais","group":2},{"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},{"name":"Listolier","group":3},{"name":"Fameuil","group":3},{"name":"Blacheville","group":3},{"name":"Favourite","group":3},{"name":"Dahlia","group":3},{"name":"Zephine","group":3},{"name":"Fantine","group":3},{"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},{"name":"Thenardier","group":4},{"name":"Cosette","group":5},{"name":"Javert","group":4},{"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},{"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},{"name":"Perpetue","group":3},{"name":"Simplice","group":2},{"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},{"name":"Woman1","group":2},{"name":"Judge","group":2},{"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},{"name":"Brevet","group":2},{"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},{"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},{"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},{"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},{"name":"Eponine","group":4},{"name":"Anzelma","group":4},{"name":"Woman2","group":5},{"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},{"name":"Gribier","group":0},{"name":"Jondrette","group":7},{"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},{"name":"Gavroche","group":8},{"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},{"name":"Magnon","group":5},{"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},{"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},{"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},{"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},{"name":"Marius","group":8},{"name":"BaronessT","group":5},{"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},{"name":"Enjolras","group":8},{"name":"Combeferre","group":8},{"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},{"name":"Feuilly","group":8},{"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},{"name":"Bahorel","group":8},{"name":"Bossuet","group":8},{"name":"Joly","group":8},{"name":"Grantaire","group":8},{"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},{"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},{"name":"Babet","group":4},{"name":"Claquesous","group":4},{"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},{"name":"Toussaint","group":5},{"name":"Child1","group":10},{"name":"Child2","group":10},{"name":"Brujon","group":4},{"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},{"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},{"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},{"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},{"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},{"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},{"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},{"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},{"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},{"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},{"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},{"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},{"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},{"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},{"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},{"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},{"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},{"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},{"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},{"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},{"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},{"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},{"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},{"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},{"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},{"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},{"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},{"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},{"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},{"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},{"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},{"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},{"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},{"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},{"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},{"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},{"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},{"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},{"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},{"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},{"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},{"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},{"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},{"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},{"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},{"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},{"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},{"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},{"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},{"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},{"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},{"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},{"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},{"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},{"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},{"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},{"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},{"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},{"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},{"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},{"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},{"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},{"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},{"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},{"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},{"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},{"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},{"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},{"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},{"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},{"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},{"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},{"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},{"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},{"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},{"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},{"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},{"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},{"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},{"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},{"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},{"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},{"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},{"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},{"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},{"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},{"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},{"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},{"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},{"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},{"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},{"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},{"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},{"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},{"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},{"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},{"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},{"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},{"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},{"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},{"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},{"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},{"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},{"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},{"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},{"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},{"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},{"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},{"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},{"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},{"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},{"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},{"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},{"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},{"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},{"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},{"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},{"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},{"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}]};

// Let's add a random "connect" value to nodes:
json.nodes = json.nodes
  .map(n => { n.connect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; return n; })

// Let's get a list of the top 10 nodes based on the value of "connect":
// By the way, the sort would modify the nodes order of the json (which is
// important to draw the force layout) and thus we create a deep copy of the
// nodes to sort them:
var top10nodes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.nodes))
  .sort( function(a, b) { return b.connect - a.connect; })
  .slice(0, 9)
  .map(n => n.name);

// And we include a "top10" boolean on each node to able to later filter them
// when drawing the label:
json.nodes = json.nodes.map( function(d) {
  if (top10nodes.indexOf(d.name) > -1) d.top10 = true;
  return d;
});

force
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(json.links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);

node.filter( function(d) { return d.top10; }).append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

---

The idea is to include a `top10` field on each node representing the fact that the `connect` field of the element has its value in the top 10 biggest:

```
var json = {"nodes":[{"name":"Myriel","group":1},{"name":"Napoleon","group":1}, ...

// Let's add a random "connect" value to nodes to simulate your dataset:
// {nodes: [{name: "Myriel", group: 1, connect: 66}, ... :
json.nodes = json.nodes
  .map(n => { n.connect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; return n; })

// Let's get a list of the top 10 nodes based on the value of "connect":
// By the way, the sort would modify the nodes order of the json (which is
// important to draw the force layout) and thus we create a deep copy of the
// nodes to sort them:
// ["MotherPlutarch", "Simplice", "Fantine", "Gueulemer", "CountessdeLo", "Count", "Perpetue", "Champtercier", "Mme.Pontmercy"]
var top10nodes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.nodes))
  .sort( function(a, b) { return b.connect - a.connect; })
  .slice(0, 9)
  .map(n => n.name);

// And we include a "top10" boolean on each node to able to later filter them
// when drawing the label:
json.nodes = json.nodes.map( function(d) {
  if (top10nodes.indexOf(d.name) > -1) d.top10 = true;
  return d;
});
```

This way the in the definition of labels, we can filter only nodes for which this `top10` field is true:

```
node.filter( function(d) { return d.top10; }).append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```